# Best api key solution for jhipster?

Tags: jhipster, okta

I am developing an api that will be eventually behind a paywall - In my scenario, clients would sign up, pay for an api tier/plan and afterwards be able to consume that api from their own apps. Depending on the tier chosen they will have certain usage limits on the api ( e.g. throttling/limits and various apis available depending on tier)

I was thinking of distributing an api_key for ease of use by clients but not sure if thats a good idea or how it would fit in with the Jhipster security model.

I guess I can just have clients sign in to grab JWT access/refresh tokens but that makes things a bit more complex for prospective clients.

Is the answer to go 'full Oauth2' and create separate 'App Clients' of an Okta Authentication server and give each customer their own "clientId + secret" that they can use to obtain access tokens ?

Any advice ?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be easy for you to go with jhipster UAA server which It serves as:

An OAuth2 Authorization Server, based on Spring Boot's implementation
An Identity Management Server, exposing a user account CRUD API

it is easy to integrate with your already jhipster tech stack and it is based on OAuth2 standard.

but for the metric and limitation part you’ll need some coding and a separate fast and high available storage to keep track of the usage of API's and a file provided to your HAproxy as a blacklist for people who reached their limit to be redirected to purchase page.

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/jhipster-uaa-secured-micro-service

Comment: looks like the microservices option has it already baked in: https://www.jhipster.tech/api-gateway/#rate_limiting

Comment: Actually, it is a faster and more optimized approach because your application wouldn’t get involved with people who haven’t purchased or finished their plan.

Comment: which solution did you mean was faster ? @ali

Comment: Adding a blackList to your HAproxy